# Regex Exact Character match without using ^

Tags: regex

I am looking for a solution that will  help me identify the following example:

`DOG: II`

The problem is the tool I use doesn't work with `^` so I may be able to find exact character matches for `II`.

If the other files have `III` then those will end up in the results.

I just want results that show `DOG: II` in the text field.

Comment: You need to make your question more clear. What tool/language are you using? When you say you can't use `^` do you mean in a character set like this: `[^abc]` or as an anchor like this: `/^a.*?b/g`? Should we expect that there could be more characters after `DOG ||` or should we only match that string if it's that value exactly? If it's the latter, why not just use a string comparison?

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking, especially your last 2 lines.

Comment: sorry the search regex function is with a vulnerability management tool called SecurityCenter. the anchor "/^" does not seem to be supported no matter how use it. I apologize i am a complete regex noobie and only started diving into it a day ago.

the Characters would be exactly DOG: I, DOG: II, DOG: III. nothing is after within that particular line.

Answer (score 0):

`/DOG:\sII[^I]/g`   would work fine

You can easily test and learn with your regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/kF0fZ1/1)

Comment: /DOG:\sII[^\w]/g  would be even better

Comment: though this works in tthe tester it did not show results within the tool. Thanks for your helping through this. i appreciate it